# Help rigging/completing model

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm not entirely sure if a question like this will get through. I've never exactly seen it asked.
But here it goes. Am I allowed to ask some one to help me complete a model. I just need to rig it, and that's something I've been struggling with. I've tried to as many tutorials I can handle and I've seen no luck getting my rig to work. 
Its a model generated using the Manuel Bastioni add-on and I found a flaw with the add-on's rigging system ( the hips don't rotate), so I wanted to rig it my self, but I nothing I do works. I add the file of what I've done so far. If any can help that would be great, whether its rigging it for me or figuring out what I'm doing wrong. I'll take any and all help.

P.s. how do I add my blend file??

Comment: If you want help doing it, then it is probably best to ask over at [Blender artists Forum](https://blenderartists.org). If you have specific technical difficulties or particular things you can't solve, then we may help you here, but you will probably need to edit your question provide more details about what you want to achieve and what exactly didn't work. Maybe some screenshots too.

Comment: To upload a file use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com . Do have in mind that from my limited time here there don't seem to be many experts in rigging/animation available around, so if your question is not answered don't take it personally, probably there's just no one around qualified enough to help you. I know very little about it myself. As it stands the question you question reads like "do it for me", so needs some rephrasing to prevent closing, please do edit it